# Updating Label/Textblock from Asynchronous method

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, prism

I'm experiencing a strange problem trying to update my UI. I am using `IProgress` to report the status of my async method, which should then update a label in my view. What is happening is the async method runs and the label is only updated when the async method completes. I am expecting the label to update multiple times while the async method is running.

While testing I noticed that if I use the Title property of the window instead of my label to show the progress of the async method, then it works exactly as expected. I do this by binding the `LblLoading` property to the Title of my view. There is only a problem updating a label or a textblock while the async method is running. Can anyone explain why this is occuring and how I might be able to solve it?

I am using MVVM and Prism. The async work is started by pressing a button which runs `InitStartup()`. Here is my worker class that does all the async work:

```
public class Worker
{
    private string _status;

    public async Task DoWork(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Status = "Test" + i;
            progress.Report(Status);
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        StartCommand = new DelegateCommand(InitStartup);
    }

    public DelegateCommand StartCommand { get; set; }

    private string _lblLoading = "TEST"; 
    public string LblLoading
    {
        get { return _lblLoading; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _lblLoading, value); }
    }

    private void InitStartup()
    {
        Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>();
        progress.ProgressChanged += UpdateProgress;

        var startup = new Worker();

        Task.Run(() => startup.DoWork(progress));
    }

    private void UpdateProgress(object sender, string status)
    {
        LblLoading = status;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="AsyncProgressTest.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    Title="{Binding LblLoading}" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding LblLoading}"/>
        <Button Content="Start" Command="{Binding StartCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why the `DoWork(IProgress<string> progress)` marked as `async`?

Comment: Why aren't you awaiting the Task.Run? An I guess the SetProprty() is to blame here. Is that prism thing? Try using good old OnPropertyChanged instead, I am guesssing the dispatcher is not propagating the results to UI thread.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I was able to reproduce the problem using INPC implementation, your point regarding dispatcher is correct

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Task.Delay` in the `DoWork` loop? It might just be over rather quickly without you having a chance to see intermediate updates.

Comment: @Haukinger I've added this option in my answer below, and it's working fine:)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski your answer is still wrong, because you give the wrong reasoning. It works fine, because with the delay we can _see_ the updates happening. Without the delay, they still happen, but aren't observable. Actually, it worked fine in the first place.

Comment: @je42 you got answer for it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) I think it should look like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public async Task DoWork(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Status = "Test" + i;
            progress.Report(Status);
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

2) You should make sure that your MainWindowViewModel was created.
I didn't understand what you try to do in this code, but with fixes, this code works fine.

**Your problem was in your DoWork method. This was done synchronously.**

Comment: No, it's started through `Task.Run`, that's perfectly fine for cpu-bound work (like `Thread.Sleep`). The problem's that `DoWork` just (nearly) immediately completes, before anyone can observe any updates. With `Thread.Sleep` or actual work done, one would see that it works fine.

Comment: Of course it works fine, the OP's code works fine, too. What's wrong is your statement `Your problem was in your DoWork method. This was done synchronously.`, because it does not matter at all whether or not it is done synchronously, because it is called through `Task.Run` anyway.